# ActionBar goes out of the screen when keyboard shows up

Tags: android, keyboard, android-actionbar

How to keep the ActionBar at its place? Look at the screenshot. Activity label is half-hidden.

[image]

Comment: Hi. I am having same issue. If I use android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" then the whole screen even the ActionBar is moved up when keyboard shows up and EditText is also visible. However if I use android :windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" to retain the ActionBar, then ActionBar doesn't goes up but the EditText is not visible now. Its somewhere behind the keyboard. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

try to use  `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` in your manifest for your 'activity' element

Comment: It works on one activity but not on another. They both are having same structure in xml. Can you please help?

Comment: @KarthikPalanivelu, could you post code for both cases (it works, and it does not work)?

Comment: I couldn't attach the code here. so created a new question. Please have a look at it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19870301/android-action-bar-hides-when-keyboard-pops-up